# Laravel Herd all URLs rewritten to index.php but a rewrite to another file neeed

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, laravel-herd

Laravel Herd by default tries to rewrite all URLs to point to the index.php file.
If I have a rule like `rewrite ^/test/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?id=$1;` it works, but `rewrite ^/test/([0-9]+)$ /test.php?id=$1;` doesn't.
I want to to have a URL rewritten to another file (e.g. file1.php) for use with a custom PHP script (non-Laravel). How can I do that?